# Ruby: capture output of system() AND print it in terminal

Tags: ruby, shell, stdout

I am trying to run a system command (`rspec`) and print its output to the terminal *in real time* and *in colour*, but I *also* want to capture its printed output in a string to use later.

At the moment it looks something like this:

```
cmd = "rspec #{ARGV.join(' ')}"
system cmd
raw = `#{cmd}`
```

This works, but since RSpec takes several seconds to complete, doubling that time is not insignificant. Is there any way to keep the `system` call printing to the terminal, but also have its output available for capture?

Comment: Have you tried ``print raw = `#{cmd}` ``?

Comment: That doesn't print the output **in colour** or **in real time**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out there is a `PTY.spawn` method that is very similar to `Open3#popen2e` but also does colour. Here's my whole block:

```
require 'pty'

raw = ''
PTY.spawn(cmd) do |stdout_err, stdin, pid|
  begin
    while (char = stdout_err.getc)
      raw << char
      print char
    end
  rescue Errno::EIO # always raised when PTY runs out of input
  ensure
    Process.waitpid pid # Wait for PTY to complete before continuing
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use [Open3#popen2e](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.4/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen2e). This method yields a stream for stdin, a stream for both stdout and stderr (they are merged), and a waiter thread.

You can safely close the stdin stream and ignore the waiter thread. You can read the merged stdout and stderr stream chunk by chunk.

Comment: Useful, but still not **in colour**.